# How to make separate login for Users and Freelancer based on Roles that is in my real time database Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hello I am working a web application with Firebase Realtime Database and Authentication with nodejs or javascript.

This is my real time database and I want to make a login form which if the User = User he will go to User Index and if the User = Freelancer he will go to Freelancer Index.

[image]

And this is the line of code that I was tweaking or trying but It doesn't go in my way.

```
        <script>

            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)
            {
                if(user)
                {
                    var userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

                    firebase.database().ref('Users/' + userID).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
                    {
                        if (snapshot.val())
                        {
                            window.location.href = "index.html";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            window.location.href = "okay.html";
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

        </script>
```

Hoping I can get feedbacks or answers here. I am almost trying it for 2days already that's why I seek help here.
Comments and answers are highly appreciated thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? And is it for Android, iOS or web?

Comment: Oh forgot to mention it was firebase web app with javascript only or nodejs @AlexMamo

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm so sorry sir. It's my first time to post here but I will do next time. Thank you!

Comment: How about doing it now, by clicking the edit link under your question? That way folks can more easily find your question going forward.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen already done sir thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With your current data structure you will need to check in two places to determine what role a user has. While this technically possible, it is less efficient and more complex in code.

I recommend instead to store a single top-level node (say `UserRoles`) where you simply keep the role for each UID:

```
"UserRoles": {
  "uidOfUser1": "Freelancer",
  "uidOfUser2": "User"
}
```

With that in place, you can load it in your `onAuthStateChanged` callback with:

```
const ref = firebase.database.ref("UserRoles");
ref.child(user.uid).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.val() === "Freelancer") {
    window.location.href = "okay.html";
  }
  else if (snapshot.val() === "User") {
    window.location.href = "index.html";
  }
  else {
    alert("Can't determine role for user: "+user.uid)
  }
});
```

Comment: As you said with top-level node "UserRoles" do I need to include it in my hashmap with UseRoles name and the value will be Freelancer or User?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. I included an example of what the JSON would look like in my answer though.

Comment: Will try it sir. But one more question. How to call data from my realtime database. For example in the image I uploaded in my post. The Roles their which is Freelancer how I am suppose to call it? cause I only know this line of code. firebase.database().ref().child("Freelancer");

How will I go down to the roles to get that Freelancer value.

Comment: You can get the role for a specific user like I show in my answer with `ref.child(user.uid)`.

Comment: @Heymonday Any update here?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response. I already solve it but not in that way. I am just having an error with my if statement. Thank you for your warm answer.

Comment: Can you post a self-answer with how you solved it in that case? That way we can bring closure to the question - and provide a helpful place for developers that land upon this page in the future.